# Div has moved down after placing another div

Tags: css

I have a facebook tab and a twitter tab on the sides of the window on the website I've coded, but in Internet Explorer they have made a big gap in between then navigation and the (soon to be) shoutbox, here it a link:

[Link](http://henrynorthen.com/exp/scarywowcata/)

Comment: What do you mean by big gap, and which browser are you using? Looks fine in Chrome

Comment: @Kyle: "...but in Internet Explorer...".

Comment: Oh.. I missed that, silly me for umm.. fast.. reading? :D Next question I guess is which version. And if it's 6, leave it :D

Comment: I think its Internet Explorer 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE8, I was able to remove the gap by moving the following code:

```
<DIV class=facebooktab><A href="http://www.facebook.com/">
<DIV class=facebook></DIV></A></DIV>
<DIV class=twittertab><A href="http://www.twitter.com/">
<DIV class=twitter></DIV></A></DIV>
```

from the DIV with the class header to the DIV with the class BODY. When those tabs are in the Header DIV, it was increasing the height of the header, thus pushing the body down further.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem, pretty simple solution too O.o thanks =)